# For which $p\in\mathbb{R}$ does $\int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2+y^2\right)^p}d\mathcal{L}^2(x,y)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

For which $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and if so, why does $\int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2+y^2\right)^p}d\mathcal{L}^2(x,y)$ exist?

---

Considering the integrand, the natural approach here would be to use polar coordinates but the integration domain doesn't seem to allow that. I have therefore tried using Fubini but I don't know how to compute $\int_0^1 1/(1+x^2+y^2)^p dy$.

How do I continue?

Comment: try polar coordinates or compute first the integral respect to $x$ using the residue theorem

Comment: @Masacroso Polar coordinates don't seem to work because of the integration domain. Is there any other way apart from the residue theorem?

Comment: polar coordinates can be used, why not? Just write the domain of integration in polar coordinates. In first place note that the range of the angle go from zero to $\pi$, now to each angle attach the needed range for the radius

Comment: anyway you dont need to evaluate the integral only see for what values of $p$ the integral converges. For this task you can try to see for what values of $p$ the integral in $x$ converges or diverges, note that the integral respect to $y$ is not so important as far the function defined by the integration in $x$ is continuous in $[0,1]$

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry, I don't really understand your last comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the integrand is non-negative then from Tonelli's theorem we have that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]}(1+x^2+y^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d (x,y)=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{\mathbb{R}}((1+y^2)+x^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d x\mathop{}\!d y\tag1
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}(C+x^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d x=C^{-p}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt C}\right)^2\right)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d x=C^{1/2-p}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+z^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d z\tag2
$$

for any $C>0$. Now note that $(1+z^2)^{-p}\sim_\infty z^{-2p}$, therefore

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+z^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d z<\infty \iff \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]}z^{-2p}\mathop{}\!d z<\infty \tag3
$$
Hence we can see that (2) is finite if and only if $p>1/2$. Then setting $K_p:=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+z^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d z$ from (1) and (2) we have

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]}(1+x^2+y^2)^{-p}\mathop{}\!d (x,y)=K_p\int_{[0,1]}(1+y^2)^{1/2-p}\mathop{}\!d y\tag4
$$

Finally note that as $f_p:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},\, y\mapsto (1+y^2)^{1/2-p}$ is continuous for any chosen $p\in \mathbb{R}$ we find that (1) is finite if and only if $p>1/2$.∎